# Why is character in string not mutated?

Tags: ruby, string

```
def test_problem(str)
  str[3].upcase! # str[3] = str[3].upcase! works
  str
end

p test_problem("hello")
```

My question is why String.upcase! which is mutating method doesn't mutate string in a case above but you need to reassign that character in string?

Answer (score 6):

`String#[]` returns a new string, [as is documented](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D).

```
a = "foo"
a.object_id
# => 70217975553640

a[0].object_id
# => 70217957574840
```

A string is not composed of character objects, it is a single object (at least on a superficial level, I'm not sure of the C internals). So there is no way to extract a character and still have it belong to the original string - you need to work with the string as a whole if you want to mutate it.

[`String#[]=`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D) on the other hand does mutate the string

You could make your method like so:

```
def test_problem(str)
  str[3] = str[3].upcase # dont use bang methods when assigning
  str
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It *does* mutate the string. But you ignore it and never look at it. Therefore, you cannot know whether it was mutated or not.